# Document manipluation: powershell

Tags: powershell, vbscript, ms-word

I am attempting to take a large document, search for a "^m" (page break) and create a new text file for each page break I find.

Using:

```
$SearchText = "^m"
$word = new-object -ComObject "word.application"
$path = "C:\Users\me\Documents\Test.doc"
$doc = $word.documents.open("$path")
$doc.content.find.execute("$SearchText")
```

I am able to find text, but how do I save the text before the page break into a new file? In VBScript, I would just do a readline and save it to a buffer, but powershell is much different.

EDIT:

```
$text = $word.Selection.MoveUntil (cset:="^m")
```

returns an error:

```
Missing ')' in method call.
```

Comment: Whether it's VBScript or PowerShell, you're still working with the Word object model, using the same methods. If you can "do a readline and save it to a buffer" in VBScript, it should be almost identical (except for syntax) in PowerShell - unless you're referring to reading a plain text file, not a Word document. I've not used Word in this way but a quick search indicates that you may want to use the [Selection object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223084(v=office.11).aspx) and `Selection.MoveEndUntil('^m')` to set the endpoint (not sure about the start point).

Comment: If this were vbscript, I would just open as a text file, but powershell is making me use the com object.

Comment: I wasn't aware that VBScript could read Word documents as though they were text. Are you talking about VBScript within Word, or from Windows Script Host (which is what I'm referring to)?

Comment: There is no VBScript within word. It is VBA which while it has the same progenitor as VBScript, it is not the same language. For an actual word document in VBScript you must use the exact same COM object as Powershell uses. In that regard, the methods that both languages use are the same. If you are working with a plain text file rather than an actual word document, that does not need the Word COM object for either VBScript or Powershell.

Comment: Is this an actual Word document? Or a plain text file?

Comment: It is a word document. And I am able to read .doc files with vbscript using set file = fso.opentextfile(path) and do while not file.atendofstream, strLine = file.readline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my solution is kinda stupid, but here is my own solution (please help me find a better one):

```
Param(
[string]$file
)
#$file = "C:\scripts\docSplit\test.docx"

$word = New-Object -ComObject "word.application"
$doc=$word.documents.open($file)
$txtPageBreak = "<!--PAGE BREAK--!>"
$fileInfo = Get-ChildItem $file
$folder = $fileInfo.directoryName
$fileName = $fileInfo.name
$newFileName = $fileName.replace(".", "")

#$findtext = "^m"
#$replaceText = $txtPageBreak

function Replace-Word ([string]$Document,[string]$FindText,[string]$ReplaceText) {

    #Variables used to Match And Replace

    $ReplaceAll = 2
    $FindContinue = 1

    $MatchCase = $False
    $MatchWholeWord = $True
    $MatchWildcards = $False
    $MatchSoundsLike = $False
    $MatchAllWordForms = $False
    $Forward = $True
    $Wrap = $FindContinue
    $Format = $False

    $Selection = $Word.Selection

    $Selection.Find.Execute(
        $FindText,
        $MatchCase,
        $MatchWholeWord,
        $MatchWildcards,
        $MatchSoundsLike,
        $MatchAllWordForms,
        $Forward,
        $Wrap,
        $Format,
        $ReplaceText,
        $ReplaceAll
    )

    $newFileName = "$folder\$newFileName.txt"
    $Doc.saveAs([ref]"$newFileName",[ref]2)
    $doc.close()
}



Replace-Word($file, "^m", $txtPageBreak)



$word.quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word)
Remove-Variable word


#begin txt file manipulation

#add end of file marker
$eof = "`n<!--END OF FILE!-->"
Add-Content $newfileName $eof

$masterTextFile = Get-Content $newFileName
$buffer = ""
foreach($line in $masterTextFile){
    if($line.compareto($eof) -eq 0){
        #end of file, save buffer to new file, be done
    }
    else {
        $found = $line.CompareTo($txtPageBreak)

        if ($found -eq 1) {
            $buffer = "$buffer $line `n"
        }

        else {
            #save the buffer to a new file (still have to write this part)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing something similar in python and compiled it to be an exe. It utilizes the search function and saves everything in the buffer to a new file.